# A href link doesn't redirect except navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

A href link doesn't redirect on page http://dreamzlive.com/career/
When I click on navigation links they works fine but doesn't work if I click on the link of content or read more link.

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Answer (score 2):

You have a script in your website that prevents it:

```
// For Demo purposes only (prevent jump on click)
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.items-wrap a')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.onclick = function() {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It is in this file:

wp-content/themes/dreamzlive/assets/script.js?ver=4.7.3

Comment: You're genius girl. It could work. My eye couldn't catch the bug. Thanks a lot. @margarita